# Close skype app and open my app dynamically after finish "skype calling"

Tags: android, skype

I can open skype activity but I dont know how to open my application after "skype calling" finish.

```
public static void skype(String number, Context ctx) {
        try {
            Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + number));
            ctx.startActivity(sky);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("SKYPE CALL", "Skype failed", e);
        }

    }
```

Close to skype after calling is enough for me first step. I searched phone broadcastrecevier but It doesnt detect anyting.